# promises in angular - POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm new to programming and was wondering why do you not need a promise on a post request, but you do on a get request?

```
var getAll = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/links'
        }).then(function(resp) {
            return resp.data;
        })
    }

    var addLink = function(link) {
        return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/links',
                data: link
            })
            //you don't need a promise on a POST!
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `$http` always returns a promise on both `GET` and `POST`. In your case, you need to do something with the data that comes back from your `GET`, so you're correctly using the promise's `then()` to run some code after the HTTP request finishes.

In your `POST`, it doesn't look like you care about the response, so you're simply *choosing* not to do anything. You could just as easily tack a `then()` onto your `POST` as well for any number of reasons.

Also, promises chain, so `then()` also returns a promise. Whatever code calls `getAll()` and `addThis()` can do something with the promise too. However, something that does `getAll().then(function(data) { ... })` will have the data from the HTTP response passed to it because of the `return resp.data` you have up there.

Code that does `addThis().then(function(data) { ... })`, in this case, will have the entire HTTP response passed to it since there's nothing processing it like in `getAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you `GET` you are going to return a response which generally requires the request to wait for some sort of response. `POST` you don't necessarily need to wait for a response. As a note, just because you don't "need" a promise on a `POST` doesn't mean you can't have one. You could add one if you so desire.